# How do I achieve a 2 -way data bind with an applied style in xaml?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, blend

I've got this bit of code in my page.xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="NameTextField" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
```

It refers to this style:

```
      <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="55" Background="White">
                    <Rectangle Stroke="#FFD9D9D9" StrokeThickness="6"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenterText" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,0" Height="42" >
                        <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" FontSize="21.333" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

This works ok when pre-populating data from the bind but does not seem to work the other way, when data is entered.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" FontSize="21.333" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

to:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=Text}" FontSize="21.333" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

TemplateBinding seems to default to a one-way bind.